# Can exponentially long bitstrings be stored in (and retrieved from) qubits reliably?

Tags: compression, quantum-computing

**The background:**

I recently read that quantum compression can be used to turn N qubits into lgN qubits (http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/quantum-bits-compressed-for-the-first-time/, inferred from the line "1 million qubits squeezed into 20"), and that piqued my curiosity about whether or not classical information could be:

```
1) converted from a bitstring to qubits,
2) compressed to lg(N) of its original size,
3) sent over a quantum network,
4) decompressed, and
5) converted from qubits to a bitstring
```

(this seems way too good to be true.)

**The questions:**

Can bitstrings be stored in (and retrieved from) qubits reliably?

Could transmission of any size N file be improved from Θ(N) to an average (not worst case) below Θ(N) when either qubits or bits can be sent over the network?

**Additional comments:**

Even if sending classical information through a quantum network is possible, I realize it might not be reliable since quantum computers have some probability of returning any answer.

Additionally, several checksums would have to be sent through a classical network to examine the validity of the decompressed information.

Comment: The article says they compressed N *identical* qubits.  If you have N classical bits which are identical, you can compress them to *one* classical bit!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I missed that while reading through. Now that you mention 'N _identical_ qubits,' the whole matter seems trivial. The info in Strilanc's first link also helped me grok how quantum compression is analogous to run-length encoding several identical classical bits. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Well, N identical *qubits* are not entirely trivial -- one cannot read out the full state of the qubit, so compressing them is a non-trivial task, unlike classically.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch that was bad word choice on my part. I meant to say that the 'N _identical_ qubits' part made Strilanc's explanation easier to grasp conceptually, which gave me a hindsight 20/20 moment. Thanks for being pedantic, though, because I would like to use precise language to make any answers and questions on this site (and elsewhere) as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum compression [only works on permutation-invariant sets of qubits](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quantum/2014/12/25/Quantum-Compression.html), which is a very strict condition that prevents it from being useful for much of anything.

In general you can't squash `n` bits of entropy into fewer than `n` qubits. This was proven all the way back in 1973 and is known as [Holevo's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holevo's_theorem):

> given n qubits, although they can "carry" a larger amount of (classical) information (thanks to quantum superposition), the amount of classical information that can be retrieved, i.e. accessed, can be only up to n classical (non-quantum encoded) bits.

Some interesting related facts:

- If you have pre-shared entanglement, you can double the capacity. With `n` pre-shared bell pairs between a sender and receiver, you can use [superdense coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdense_coding) to pack `2n` bits into `n` transmitted qubits (the already-transmitted bell pair parts play the role of the other `n` qubits).
- What if you only want to get `n` bits out, but *different* bits in different situations? Can we make an exponentially huge dictionary with linearly sized entries? Nope: [quantum advice](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2003/07/quantum-advice.html) is not more space-efficient than classical advice.
- What if you used quantum compression to send `2^n` identical copies of `a|0> + b|1>`, and then  the receiver statistically inferred `a` based on how many 0s they measured? Is this roundabout way of sending real numbers more efficient? Nope: the standard deviation of the statistic (~1/sqrt(2^n)) is worse than the precision you get from sending `n` bits of binary (1/2^n).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. All four articles were good reads. I'm sure it will take a long time (forever?) to fully understand the articles, but it's very cool to think about.